# Show that two Lagrange functions are equivalent

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

I saw the following question in a practice sheet and am a bit confused:

> Given the lagrange function $L=\frac{1}{2}\dot{r}^2 -\frac{a}{r^2}-b r^2$, were $a$ and $b$ are constant. Show that a new lagrange function $L'$ is equivalent to $L$, were $L'$ is $L$ in a new variable $s=\frac{1}{r}$

So I calculated the Euler Lagrange equations for above cases and came to:

1. $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{r}}=\ddot{r}=2a\frac{1}{r^3}-2br= \frac{\partial L}{\partial r} $
2. $\frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L'}{\partial\dot{s}}=\frac{1}{\ddot{s}^3}=2as-2b\frac{1}{s^3}= \frac{\partial L'}{\partial s} $

How can I now show that 1. and 2. are equivalent?

EDIT: I edited a stupid mistake out (see comments).

Comment: Write these ELEs respectively as $f(r,\,\dot{r},\,\ddot{r})=0,\,g(s,\,\dot{s},\,\ddot{s})=0$, then rewrite $g$ as a function of $r,\,\dot{r},\,\ddot{r}$ using $s=1/r\implies\dot{s}=-\dot{r}/r^2$ etc.

Comment: $1/\ddot s^3$ is definitely not equal to $\ddot r^3$. Fixing this should give you the correct result.

Comment: You have $\dot r = -\frac{\dot s}{s^2}$ (also the L' in your post is wrong) and $\ddot s=\frac{2\dot r^2 - r \ddot r}{r^3}$

Comment: Now substitute back $s$, $\dot s$ and $\ddot s$ in terms of $r$ and its derivatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, $L$ has ELE$$\ddot{r}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{r}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial r}=\frac{2a}{r^3}-2br.$$Since $\color{blue}{s=r^{-1}}$, $\color{blue}{\dot{s}=-r^{-2}\dot{r}}$ and $\color{blue}{\ddot{s}=2r^{-3}\dot{r}^2-r^{-2}\ddot{r}}$, and$$r=s^{-1}\implies\frac12\dot{r}^2=\frac12(-s^{-2}\dot{s})^2=\frac12s^{-4}\dot{s}^2.$$Since $L^\prime=\frac12s^{-4}\dot{s}^2-as^2-bs^{-2}$, its ELE is$$s^{-4}\ddot{s}-4s^{-5}\dot{s}^2=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{s}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial s}=-2as+2bs^{-3}.$$Now subtitute the blue equations into this to show it reduces to the original ELE.

Comment: Thank you for your help!